# Open link to Facebook page from iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook

I want to redirect user to my App's Facebook page, so I have the following code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:
    [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://facebook.com/myAppsPage"]];
```

this works great, if there is no Facebook app on device. Then the link opens in Safari.

If there is Facebook app installed on device, then after executing above code Facebook app opens, but it is showing users timeline, not my app's page. I tried to change link to `@"fb://pages/myAppsPage"` and to `@"fb://profile/myAppsPage`, but this again opened users timeline.

So, my question is: how can I open my apps page in safari, if there is no Facebook app, or in Facebook app, if the one is installed.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You have to use the facebook ID for the given page rather than the vanity URL. To get the pages ID, enter your page's vanity name at the following URL and copy the value for "id":

https://graph.facebook.com/yourappspage

Once you have the id, you can set up the method to check if FB is installed using the canOpenURL method and serve the appropriate content for both states:

```
NSURL *facebookURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile/113810631976867"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:facebookURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:facebookURL];
} else {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://facebook.com"]];
}
```

Comment: No problem. Just be aware, URL schemes are almost completely undocumented and it's up to Facebook to continue to support this feature. They could make breaking changes to it at any given time.

Comment: Thanks for the great tip of using `fb://profile/xxxxx` that works well in current version of Facebook app. Had been searching over the internet for a solution, the suggestion of using of `fb://page/xxxxx` which does **not** work, no page is loaded, probably that's for older version of Facebook app.

Comment: Confirmed that this is still working successfully on iOS7 and iOS8.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore with the deprecation of IDs by Facebook.

Comment: `fb://profile/113810631976867` still works because it is an organization page, but if I insert userID for accessing user's profile page -> I get "page not found"! Any solutions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37199854/swift-open-facebook-profile-by-facebookuid @virusss8

Comment: In iOS 9 remember to whitelist the scheme by adding the array key `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in your Info.plist and the item `fb` as a string item inside the array.

Comment: Remark with the sample code: Instead of going to the facebook homepage "https://www.facebook.com" when the facebook app is not installed, going to your apps facebookpage "https://facebook.com/myAppsPage" might be more desirable.

Comment: A trailing slash / seems necessary in fb://profile/PageID, so it must be fp://profile/PageID/.

Comment: "fb://profile?id=PageName" working iOS 14 with FB

Answer (score 38):

It seems that since the last answer Facebook have changed the scheme for pages (profile is same as before)

the `page_id` is now the part of URL query.
So in order to redirect to fb app, the url has to be in the format:

```
fb://page/?id=your_page_numeric_id
```

Also make sure to whitelist `fb` scheme in your apps `Info.plist`

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fb</string>
</array>
```

In case there will be any further modifications or you don't know your facebook page's `page_id`, you can extract the precise iOS `fb` URL from your Facebook web page source.

1. Open your Facebook page in Safari
2. Right click -> Inspect Element
3. Search for `al:ios:url`

You should be able to find:

```
<meta property="al:ios:url" content="fb://page/?id='your_page_numeric_id'">
```

Copying this URL into your app and then calling:

```
guard let facebookURL = NSURL(string: "fb://page/?id=your_page_numeric_id") else {
    return
}

if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(facebookURL)) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(facebookURL)
} else {

    guard let webpageURL = NSURL(string: "http://facebook.com/yourPage/") else {
        return
    }

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(webpageURL)
}
```

should do the job...

Comment: Since this answer is over a year old: I can confirm that this method (fb://event?id=<eventID> in my case) works as of this comment. On iOS 10 and newest Facebook app version.

Comment: somehow it doesn't work for me though and it's Feb 6th , lol; it only open my own page that i'm currently logged in with ..

Comment: Confirmed working for iOS 10. As OP mentioned, you need to open your FB page in Safari to get the correct `al:ios:url`

Comment: Great secret looking for that `al:ios:url` property! I just used it to find how to deeplink a facebook group (not a page). cheers

Answer (score 30):

I was happy to find skladek's answer, so here's my contribution: Swift + other social networks.

I found that I needed 3 forward slashes for twitter, and only 2 for Facebook and Google+, I didn't investigate more than that…

```
// Go to https://graph.facebook.com/PageName to get your page id
func openFacebookPage() {
    let facebookURL = NSURL(string: "fb://profile?id=PageName")!
    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(facebookURL) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(facebookURL)
    } else {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://www.facebook.com/PageName")!)
    }
}

func openTwitterProfile() {
    let twitterURL = NSURL(string: "twitter:///user?screen_name=USERNAME")!
    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(twitterURL) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(twitterURL)
    } else {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://twitter.com/USERNAME")!)
    }
}

func openGooglePlusPage() {
    let googlePlusURL = NSURL(string: "gplus://plus.google.com/u/0/PageId")!
    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(googlePlusURL) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(googlePlusURL)
    } else {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://plus.google.com/PageId")!)
    }
}
```

An attempt at refactoring:

```
struct SocialNetworkUrl {
    let scheme: String
    let page: String

    func openPage() {
        let schemeUrl = NSURL(string: scheme)!
        if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(schemeUrl) {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(schemeUrl)
        } else {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: page)!)
        } 
    }
}

enum SocialNetwork {
    case Facebook, GooglePlus, Twitter, Instagram
    func url() -> SocialNetworkUrl {
        switch self {
        case .Facebook: return SocialNetworkUrl(scheme: "fb://profile/PageId", page: "https://www.facebook.com/PageName")
        case .Twitter: return SocialNetworkUrl(scheme: "twitter:///user?screen_name=USERNAME", page: "https://twitter.com/USERNAME")
        case .GooglePlus: return SocialNetworkUrl(scheme: "gplus://plus.google.com/u/0/PageId", page: "https://plus.google.com/PageId")
        case .Instagram: return SocialNetworkUrl(scheme: "instagram://user?username=USERNAME", page:"https://www.instagram.com/USERNAME")
        }
    }
    func openPage() {
        self.url().openPage()
    }
}
```

Now you can call:

```
SocialNetwork.Twitter.openPage()
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work, because of the url.

I have to change the url from "fb:///profile/PageId" to "fb://profile/PageId"

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @NutchaphonRewik, I ended up using // and not /// for fb but forgot to edit my answer. It's corrected now.

Comment: Definitely the best answer! Thx

Comment: In my case, "fb://profile/PageId"- its opening News Feed; not the Facebook page :(

Comment: @AviC Did you make sure you changed the page value (replacing PageName)?

Comment: Yes absolutely. My code is in Swift & my device has IOS- 9.3.3. The else-part is working fine (opening the FB-page-URL in browser). But, using the same pageID- its  opening my News-Feed screen- if Facebook is there. Can you please test once in IOS 9.3.3 !!

Comment: @AviC I just tested under 9.3.5. Sorry to insist but just in case: you need to change both PageId and PageName in the facebook line.

Comment: Okk. Then some issue in my pageId. I will re-check. Thanks a lot man for your active support :))

Comment: anyone knows how to do this same for snapchat

Answer (score 11):

For iOS 9, You must whitelist the url's that your app will call out to using the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes key in your Info.plist.

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987986/ios-9-not-opening-instagram-app-with-url-scheme).

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
     <string>fb</string>
     <string>fbapi</string>
     <string>fbauth2</string>
     <string>fbshareextension</string>
     <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
     <string>twitter</string>
     <string>whatsapp</string>
     <string>wechat</string>
     <string>line</string>
     <string>instagram</string>
     <string>kakaotalk</string>
     <string>mqq</string>
     <string>vk</string>
     <string>comgooglemaps</string>
    </array>
```

Answer (score 3):

I just found this URL scheme `fb://profile?id={userid/username/pageid}`, and it is working fine as of 30 Aug 2020.

eg: `fb://profile?id=4` OR `fb://profile?id=zuck`

Warning: Please use at your own risk as this is not documented in Facebook developers documentation. This URL scheme may be removed by Facebook app in the future without any warning and indication.

Comment: I've found it posted in 2018 here and confirm it works, so it should be "quite stable" URL scheme: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-are-all-the-custom-url-schemes-supported-by-the-facebook-iphone-app

Comment: Working solution Oct 2020

Comment: I searched so much. Pretty much everything is outdated. This is the correct answer Sep 2021.

Answer (score 1):

After much testing I have found one of the most effective solutions:

```
NSString *facebookID = @"XXXXXXXXXX";
NSString *facebookURL = @"www.facebook.com/XXXXXXXX";
NSURL *urlModal = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"fb://facewebmodal/f?href=%@", facebookURL]];
NSURL *urlWithID = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"fb://page/%@", facebookID]]; // or "fb://profile/%@" or another type of ID
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:facebook_url];


if(facebookID && !facebookID.isEmpty && [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:urlWithID]) {
    // open facebook app with facebookID
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:urlWithID];
} else if (facebookURL && !facebookURL.isEmpty && [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:urlModal]) {
    // open facebook app with facebookUrl
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:urlModal];
} else if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url]) {
    // somehow open
    NSLog(@"%@%@",@"Failed to open url:",[url description]);
}
```

Order of sentences "if else" vary to your liking ...

Enjoy it!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 2.3**

For code you can use this example:

Note: If you can't find the facebook profile id can you use the follow site to do it (https://findmyfbid.com/)

```
func goFacebook() {
    let profileID = "" //Here put profile id Example:'62260589592'
    let facebookURL = NSURL(string: "fb://profile/\(profileID)")!

    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(facebookURL) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(facebookURL)
    } else {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://www.facebook.com/PageName")!)
    }
}
```

For Info.plist you need set the follow parameters:

Note: For open the Info.plist on Source Mode

-Go to Info.plist file and click right

-Select "Open As"

-Select "Source Code"

-Put code above of another

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
 <string>fb</string>
 <string>fbapi</string>
 <string>fbauth2</string>
 <string>fbshareextension</string>
 <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 1):

// Swift 5, you can use this function to open fb page/profile

```
       func openFacebookPage() {
            let facebookURL = NSURL(string: "fb://profile/PageId")!
            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(facebookURL as URL) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(facebookURL as URL)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.open(NSURL(string: 
             "https://www.facebook.com/PageName")! as URL)
           }
      }
//By Using PageId or name only
      func openFacebookPage(pageID:String) {
            let facebookURL = NSURL(string: "fb://profile/\(pageID)")!
            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(facebookURL as URL) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(facebookURL as URL)
         } else {
             UIApplication.shared.open(NSURL(string: "https://www.facebook.com/\ 
           (pageID)")! as URL)
         }
     }
//By Using Url only
     func openFacebookPageURL(url:String) {
               let facebookURL = NSURL(string: url)!
               if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(facebookURL as URL) {
               UIApplication.shared.open(facebookURL as URL)
            } else {
               UIApplication.shared.open(NSURL(string: url)! as URL)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please provide explanation to your answer for better understanding.