# Getting error "This App is not available for your phone" when opening facebook page from iphone app

Tags: ios, facebook, url

I am having an app in which I am opening my Facebook Like page.

I am using this  [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589367/open-link-to-facebook-page-from-ios-app?rq=1) for that.

But when I try to open this It doesn't go to my Facebook Like page.

It opens up my app with Logo but there is no like page for my app.

It says `" This app is not available for your phone."`

I have passed the correct AppId from Facebook.

Do I need to set up any additional details from Facebook Developers Guide?

Please help me. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How did you found the App ID for your Page?

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/yourappspage

Comment: It is also listed on my facebook developer's page in apps section where my app page is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my application, I am using this code and it works pretty well. Seems like you are doing something wrong.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile/268179536658143"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url])
{
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```

EDIT: You were taking App ID, not the fan page ID. Please correct it.

Comment: Yes, I am also doing the same thing. Can you please tell me what things need to set up from Facebook Developers guide?

Comment: Nothing needs to be setup from the developers guide. If you want the above code to work the only mandatory thing is to have the Facebook Official Application installed on your phone.

Comment: Hey , You need to use the Facebook Page ID not the App ID, seems like this is the thing you are doing wrong !!

Comment: Under the facebook developers guide->apps->my appname->settings->Appid/APIKey. Right?

Comment: Nope, That's App ID, you want to open the page, You need the Facebook Fan Page ID bro :D

Comment: Ohhh!From Where do i get that?

Comment: Thanks man. I was taking the wrong fan page appid. You can find your fan page app id just by clicking on your profile picture of your fan page and in your browser the last number from your url is your fan page appid.