# How to open an https Facebook page from iOS device?

Tags: ios, https, facebook-sdk-3.0

Im trying to open my Facebook app page from iPhone.
Im using this:

> [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL
>   URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com/(my page name)"]];

Unfortunately, this redirects to https protocol, and because of that the device is unable to open the page.

What can I do to open this page?

Answer (score 1):

pass your `Page ID - xxxxxx` not the page Name

```
 [UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile/herepassyourPageID"]];
```

or

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.facebook.com/herepassyourPageID (id, not name)"]];
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll see if this works (once i'm home to try this out)!

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar -- Sure Man, if u need assistance i hope with u m have a happy day

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaken by using page name instead of page ID.
You should use something like below:

```
NSURL *facebookURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile/{pageid}"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:facebookURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:facebookURL];
} else {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""https://www.facebook.com/{pageid}"]];
}
```

**[If desired]:** You should check the availability of installed facebook app to open the page, as shown in the above code sample.

Comment: Im curious why the page Id is required? Because when i use the page name in the URL from my desktop browser, it works just fine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589367/open-link-to-facebook-page-from-ios-app