# How to open the Facebook app on a specific profile from your iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, deep-linking

A few days ago, the deep link I used for opening a Facebook profile directly in the Facebook app (if installed) stopped working. It opens the Facebook app, but displays the error message "This content isn't available".

My current implementation:

```
if application.canOpenURL(URL(string:"fb://")!) {
    if let appUrl = URL(string: "fb://profile?id=\(profile)") {
        application.open(appUrl)
    } else {
        print("couldn't open facebook url")
    }
}
```

Value added to Queried URL Schemes in **Info.plist**: *fb* (this was enough).
Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

you can use like this

eg: `fb://profile?id=4` OR `fb://profile?id=zuck` but this URL scheme may be removed by Facebook app in the future without any warning and indication.

Source ([Swift Open Facebook Profile by FacebookUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37199854/swift-open-facebook-profile-by-facebookuid))

Comment: This is exactly what I was using, but it stopped working unfortunately