# App link to open iOS Facebook app and direct to a particular post

Tags: ios, facebook

Is it possible to open Facebook app and showing a particular post on iOS?

I only managed to open Facebook app but cannot jump to a post with post id.
If use normal https URL, Safari can directly open that post.

I followed this question [Open link to Facebook page from iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589367/open-link-to-facebook-page-from-ios-app), but i am looking for a solution to a post, not company page.

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589367/open-link-to-facebook-page-from-ios-app

Comment: @Anbu.Karthink. I can open a Facebook PAGE, but how about a POST? I tried fb://pageid, it open my Facebook page, but fb://profile/pageid_postid or fb://post/pageid_postid, does not work as expected

Comment: can you updated the questiion ,