# iOS Facebook URL schemes doesn't open page in facebook app

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, fbsdk, swift4.1

I need to open facebook page in facebook app.

This is my code

```
 let url : URL!
 if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:"fb://")!)) {
    //FIXME: Url is not working ✋
    let pageName = "google"
      // tried with fb://page?name=%@ not worked
    let urlString =  String.init(format: "fb://page?id=%@",pageName!) 
    url = URL.init(string: urlString)
 } else {
    url = URL.init(string: "https://www.facebook.com/google")
 }

if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url!, completionHandler: nil)
} else {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url!)
}
```

it perfectly works in safari browser but not in facebook app.

I have added the url schem in `inof.plist`

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fb</string>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
    </array>
```

Can anyone help me to get out this problem?

Thanks In Advance!!!!

Answer (score 0):

try this code , make sure use facebook id from page not page name

check this [How to find page Id](https://www.labnol.org/internet/find-facebook-page-id-profile/6909/)

```
 let url : URL!
        if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:"fb://")!)) {
            //FIXME: Url is not working ✋
            let pageName = "104958162837"
            // tried with fb://page?name=%@ not worked
            let urlString =  String.init(format: "fb://profile/%@",pageName) 
            url = URL.init(string: urlString)
        } else {
            url = URL.init(string: "https://www.facebook.com/104958162837")
        }

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url!, completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url!)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

And is it opening in a browser when you call `UIApplication.shared.openURL(:)`?

I didn't **exactly** understand your problem, but if I'm not mistaken, you've to put the **Facebook App ID** (it's the first thing that appears in your app in [developers.facebook](https://developers.facebook.com)) in your URL Types.

This image should clarify what I'm trying to say:

[image]

Do not forget the `"fb"` `String` **before** your **App ID**.

---

**EDIT:** Now that I've understood your problem, I **can't be sure** that you will be able to solve this - as you can see all [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589367/open-link-to-facebook-page-from-ios-app)-, **they apparently don't seem to work anymore**, as the URL scheme changed a couple of times, and the one that you're using is actually the last "answered/used" on the referenced answer.
I can **almost** confirm that there is no *supported* way to do what you're trying because of [this answer in fb-sdk github issues](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-swift/issues/173).

Comment: I am checking that if fb app is available in device, open page in fb app. if not, open page in, UIWebView..... but the problem is that It's not open a page in facebook app. I already added the "fb"MyID in URL Types.

Comment: Oh, now I've fully understood. I will update my answer, your problem is probably that you're trying to open in an URL on the fb app, and that's not the way you do it.